# Manage files as a fixed grid in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I find myself constantly diving my screen in two in the middle and setting one file on each side in IntelliJ.

Are there any plug-ins that can assist with this? Something that makes it work similarly to a tiled window manager.

Comment: Why you need two tabs in screen? is it just because you love to work this way, or you use it for comparing or another purpose?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki: sometimes I use three, but most of the time two is the maximum that I can have and still be comfortable. I'm not comparing anything, I'm often switching between files or having on as reference while I work in the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a keyboard shortcut to the command that allows vertical window splitting. Go to `File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> Keymap` and there search for split. Select the correct record, right click and `Add keyboard shortcut`.

Comment: I would make the further suggestion that `Ctrl-S` should be used as a shortcut. The `S` stands for "split". Ctrl-S is originally to save files, but IntelliJ automatically save files, so there is no need to use this shortcut for that.

Comment: @MarcG I would go otherwise: Ctrl+S is used to save in so many applications that I find myself pressing it almost as a reflex. Same as Ctrl+C/V...

Comment: @Matthieu I also have this reflex, which I always wanted to get rid of. I've been pressing useless `CTRL-S` in IntelliJ for years, and it just makes you waste time. Remapping `CTRL-S` for splitting the screen is actually helping me in the process of killing this reflex.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for quite a bit more control over your editor tabs, give the plugin [Tab Shifter](https://github.com/dkandalov/tab-shifter) a try. This increases your ability to navigate split panes via keyboard shortcuts quite considerably over what IntelliJ provides natively.

If you're happy to just split your panes using native key mappings as suggested by other answers (`File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> Keymap`) the plugin `Tab to Next Splitter` could help considerably as well when you need to move which pane your want a file to belong to. This plugin allows you to move the active file to a different pane via a keyboard shortcut as opposed to needing to click and drag and saves a bunch of time.

Hope this helps!